# How could Adam HaRishon have contained all the souls that would ever be inside of him, including evil, even before the sin?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, sin, adam, reincarnation, yaakov-and-eisav

I recall a concept from the teachings of the Arizal and elsewhere that before eating of the tree of knowledge, Adam HaRishon contained all the souls that would ever exist within him, but the good and evil ones were separate in their proper places. Then when he ate, they all got mixed together within him. (I recall an Ohr HaChaim source for the latter but I spent the last hour looking for it and can't find it. I hope I'm not misremembering).

I recall an Arizal that Moshiach will be a gilgul of Adam HaRishon. And (not sure of source) perhaps all of Israel are represented by Adam.

I recall a third concept that when Adam HaRishon sinned, he created his opposite, which I recall reading different versions that this was Esau, or this was the nachash, or this was the samech mem, or this was Adam Bellail.

Here are the questions:

1. Given that Moshiach and the nachash are opposites, how can we say that when Adam sinned, he created his opposite (the nachash), given that Bereshit 3:1 proves the nachash already existed before Adam's sin?
2. How can Adam represent Israel if he already contained all the souls within him from creation, including the unholy ones, given that Israel's souls in their essence are all holy?
3. If we say that Adam in fact only contained holy souls before the sin, and that his sin was what caused evil souls to come into existence and mix with the holy souls, would that mean that Hashem did not create evil people, rather Adam's actions did? Would that mean that Hashem would be the Creator only of holy man, while Adam's sin would be the creator of evil man? Although of course, all of creation would still only possible and subsisting because of Hashem, I am just asking about a more specific distinction within that fact. To add clarity, I don't ask in the sense that Hashem creates only good, but through our actions even good people can tar our own souls with evil. Of course, only good comes from Hashem. Rather, what I'm asking about is would Adam's sin have brought into existence *new* souls, all of the evil souls that would ever exist in all of creation, in contradistinction to the idea that Hashem created those too when He created Adam all of them were within Adam from the beginning.
4. If we say Adam only contained the holy souls within him, and also that his sin did *not* create the evil souls but rather it only mixed good and evil *that already existed* souls together, then where would the evil souls have existed before he sinned if not within him? Or, if we posit the opposite and say that Adam *did* contain both all the holy souls and all the evil souls within him before the sin, then in that case, how could the nachash exist somewhat independently, with an independent will, and be able to go talk to Eve by the etz daas away from Adam? If Adam contained all the souls in him already then shouldn't no living being with a soul have been able to exist outside of him at that point? Many do say the nachash was technically an angel (or an animal since serpents are animals), so if Adam is said to have only had all the *human* souls in him, something I don't remember well, then that would be one way to answer the question, but in that case I would amend the question to specify how it could be reconciled with the interpretation that the nachash was a man, like Esau. If we go off the interpretation that the nachash was Esau, how could we say that all the souls including the evil souls were already within Adam?

I include these questions in the same post because they're focused on reconciling the same concepts, and answers to each of them may affect the others. I recall having learned these concepts that now, due to more knowledge many years later, I am having trouble reconciling. I recall some of the sources for them, but not very specifically, and not others, so please help source the teachings if you know them and know the texts and page numbers.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I recommend first verifying your sources before asking questions.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380776/jewish/Effect-of-The-Sin-of-Adam-32.htm I also recommend to narrow your questions down to 1 question.

Comment: I recommend @Shmuel's link. What you need, to sort all this out, is recognise there are two souls in each Jew, and pious non-Jew - the human soul, which contains all the evil and some good, and the Divine soul, which is pure. Adam had both of these souls, but was only able to pass on the Divine soul to one offspring, and so it was until Avraham, and finally by the time of Israel, all of his children would inherit it (via the mother). Chabad Chassidus deals with this at length, start with the above sources.

Comment: All the questions are the same question. Since by sinning Adam created a mirror image of himself, therefore the mirror image of himself and the real self were now confused in the same persona. *Mashiach* liberates the *ruchniyos* in the mirror image.

Comment: See Eruvin 18 and the Ben Yehoyada there.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Would the mirror image of Adam would be the nachash though? Because the nachash already existed before Adam sinned, so how can we say Adam created his mirror image when he sinned? These distinctions are why I broke it down into each element because every detail causes a potential contradiction with another detail, so it has to be dealt with specifically. Did the non-Jewish souls exist before Adam sinned? Were they within Adam or external (I.e. maybe the nachash contained with him all the non-Jewish souls and Adam contained all the Jewish souls. That would solve some contradictions)

Comment: @RabbiKaii So would it be incorrect to say Adam represented Israel? Of course Abraham does as the first Jew. As you said, it wasn't until Abraham that Adam was able to pass on the Divine soul only. So if before that he had both, how can he represent Israel? Wouldn't he represent all mankind including the non-Jew? https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/1017961/jewish/Why-Were-Humans-Created-Twice.htm says Bereshit 1 speaks of animal called Adam, and Bereshit 2 speaks of G-dly soul of man called Adam. If both are Adam, what third entity is the serpent then?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Maybe u could say Adam of Bereshit 1 is Israel's nefesh, and Adam of Bereshit 2 is Israel's ruach or neshamah, and the serpent is the gentiles nefesh, but then shouldn't there also be a 2nd serpent to represent the gentiles ruach or neshamah in kind? Either you have one Adam and one serpent, the mirror of Adam, or two Adam's then you need 2 serpents, 2 mirrors. This is before even getting to the complicating factors of how the serpent pre-existed Adam's sin if Adam's sin created his opposite, or rumored interpretations where the serpent is holy serpent Yaakov and Adam is Edom/Esau

Comment: @RabbiKaii or where Israel's souls and the gentiles souls existed before the sin. When Hashem created Adam, did He create Adam with Israel's souls and the gentiles souls within him? Or only Israel's souls? 

Put more simply, which souls were in Adam of Bereshit 1? Which souls were in Adam of Bereshit 2? Which souls were in the serpent? Then once we have those answers, we can ask about how to reconcile them with regards to questions like how could Yaakov be the holy serpent if Israel is Adam not the serpent, and how could Adam's sin have created his opposite if the serpent already existed.

Comment: @Shmuel Thank you very much Shmuel. I've read that before but I don't have it memorized because there are many contradicting teachings which makes it harder to remember each one since it's not always consistent. I just read it again. It says when Adam sinned, he blemished the majority of sparks of nefesh, ruach, and neshama, causing them to fall into the sitra achra. It doesnt answer if he contained only Israel sparks before the sin or also gentile sparks. Well, it says he contained "all that exists," in which case how were the animals and the serpent to some degree external to him?

Comment: @Shmuel And since the nachash already existed before he sinned, how can we say that his sin created his opposite? The article is helpful but doesn't fully reconcile everything. I don't like to write long questions, it takes a lot more time, so I only did it because every detail was important. It's what made it difficult for me to reconcile and probably will make it difficult to answer but I'm hopeful. I rly appreciate the article and everyone's posts to help answer it. Rereading that was a good memory refresher too.

Comment: @ShipBuilding I really appreciate your strong interest in this subject. It's very complicated, but also it's all very well laid down in the maamarot, so best not to try to guess these things, but simply look them up. Simply speaking, there are only two types of soul we can have, human and Divine (Tanya 1), Adam had both, and Israel and pious gentiles have both. Everyone else has just a human soul. The serpent was just an animal with an animal soul, not a human soul. It embodied the Yeitzer Hara, see Rishonim. But yes, Adam represented/contained all of mankind. I recommend going and studying!

Comment: @ShipBuilding The Maharal says that the *nachash* was the mirror image of Adam. I think what he means though is that the potential for a mirror image of Adam existed prior to the sin, but was only instantiated through the sin. This is in accordance with the Maharal's position that Hashem never created evil.

Comment: @ShipBuilding Thanks that's helpful. It would be interesting to find a reconcilation with the teaching that Adam's opposite only came into being after he sinned. I know u said he addressed that with it only existed in potential before, but Torah shows the nachash talking to Havah before the sin, so can in-potential things that don't exist speak? Even if it's telepathically or spiritually, not literal speech, can it do that in-potential if it doesnt exist yet?

"The Maharal's position that Hashem never created evil." Can we say Hashem created righteous ppl and Adam is the creator of evil ppl?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE With that last 1 the distinction Im going for is do we say Hashem created all of humanity, not just Israel and righteous among the nations, and even tho some of humanity turned out evil, thats only because he gave them free choice and they became that way, or, do we say Hashem created only holy souls period, and it was Adam's sin that brought into existence the "opposite," meaning all the evil souls? Do we say Hashem did not create evil souls in Adam, but rather Adam's sin brought them into being?Or did he alrdy have the evil souls in him by Hashem's doing & his sin only mixed them?

Comment: @Harel13 Thanks Harel for not down voting, haha. I would post the sources if I knew them. I didnt know Mi Yodega existed years ago when I learned many things and had questions. Years later I learn new things which create new questions about what I learned years before, how to reconcile the new learning with the old, but I dont remember the old sources. For questions I ask about what I learn now where I have the source I will always include them.

Comment: @ShipBuilding According to the *mussar* / kabbalistic definition of evil which is one who is lacking within themselves and therefore seeks to be nurtured through the life source of other people, these questions are invalid, since evil is not "is", rather it "is not".

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I meant rashas or people with souls from the sitra achra. I will repost with the changed terminology to make it clearer. "

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Do we say Hashem created all of humanity,not just Israel and righteous of the nations,and even tho some of humanity became rashas,thats only because He gave them free choice and they became that way,or, do we say Hashem created only holy souls period, and it was Adam's sin that brought into existence the "opposite," meaning all the souls of the sitra achra, of the non-righteous nations? Do we say Hashem did not create non-righteous nations souls in Adam, but rather Adam's sin brought them into being?Or did he alrdy have those souls in him by Hashem's doing & his sin only mixed them?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE If you're anything like me, you have read opinions that addressed one aspect of this differently than other opinions, but did not address other aspects, and then still more opinions that addressed other aspects but not the prior aspect, and may have had conflicting opinions on that aspect as well. So it's difficult to answer and understandable if even most of the most learned people in a place like this don't know the answer off hand and it might even take them weeks to track down, I cant say. Or it could be easy for some to answer, I dont know, but my hunch is it is a difficult one

Comment: @ShipBuilding There is a difference between stolen *tzurah* and stolen *chomer*.

Answer (score 1):

See Eruvin 18 where Gemara tells of how Adam seperated from Chava after the sin for 130 years and emitted nocturnal seed while sleeping. See Arizal's Shaar Hapesukim on Shemos (1:8) for a lengthy discussion about how all souls, good and bad, are rooted in Adam. Ben yehoyada mentions this Arizal to explain the generation of the flood, tower of Bavel, the people of sedom, and the peolpe in mitzrayim in Bava Metzia 44a s.v "Mi shepara"

שער הפסוקים - פרשת שמות
כי אדה"ר היה כולל כל הנשמות, והיה כולל כל העולמות. וכשחטא, נפלו ממנו כל הנשמות ההם לתוך הקליפות, הנחלקות לשבעים אומות "B/c Adam included all souls, and all worlds. And when he sinned, all the souls fell into the klipos, which were divided into the 70 nations..."

Comment: Thank you. Can you include in your answer an answer to the confusion over Israel vs gentiles? I've seen comments that only Jews reincarnate, not gentiles, yet I've read many midrash about reincarnations of figures like Nimrod and I believe even post-flood villains. Do I infer that everyone was part of Israel to start? Or were they mistaken about that? 

Because I am familiar with the sources you mentioned but they don't specify how Adam Harishon could include all souls, but also be a prior incarnation of Moshiach and Jacob who are specifically Israelite souls not gentile souls.

Comment: To say Adam included all souls and all worlds suggests he was both Jew and non-Jew, whereas he should just be a Jew if he was a prior incarnation of Moshiach. I am looking for a reconcilation to this specifically and still have not found 1. The origin of Israel's souls come from Hashem's essence, but when was the origin of the non-Jewish souls?

Actually I have not read Gate of Verses in years so I shouldnt say I am familiar with that Arizal. Maybe the answer is there. I will recheck ur sources and in the meantime please let me know if you remember a summary for this specific reconcilation.

Comment: Also speaking of not remembering, I never recalled it reconciling the issue, but I thought I remembered an Or Hachaim that at least put forward one clear opinion on the different souls mixing after the sin. But now when I search in sefaria the closest I find is a verse about the "gentile kings," which I also remember, but I cant remember if that's the verse I was remembering, or if there was a more comprehensive one also that I cant find because maybe Im looking at the wrong translation on sefaria now than before. I should have saved it to sheet the first time but I didnt. No bookmark either.